# Setup of SVN for test and live directories

Tags: linux, svn

We have an application that has the live version of the site in one directory and the test version of the server in another directory.  In the SVN setup, should we have them in separate projects or is there a better way of doing that so we can migrate our changes from the test server to the live on periodic release dates?

Any help on this process would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single SVN-repo for the staging & production, is a good way. Separate projects may have undesirable results.

Comment: I have been reading up a lot, is it better to have branches like dev and live or something?

Comment: Usually trunk is a development mainstream, the branches are for variants, the tags are for fixing the versions and rollback changes in several cases.